# knife ssh cloud.public_ipv4 json array trouble

Tags: arrays, json, chef-infra, google-compute-engine, knife

Command:

```
knife ssh name:node-name "some-command" -VV -a cloud.public_ipv4
```

Output:

```
.......
DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::JSONToModelOutput#handle_response
DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::JSONInput#handle_response
DEBUG: Adding ["node-ip-address"]
DEBUG: establishing connection to ["node-ip-address"]:22
WARNING: Failed to connect to ["node-ip-address"] -- SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

In GCE you could add several static external IPs to one instance, in that way json output would be like an array:

```
"public_ipv4": ["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2", "...."]
```

In case of only one external ip it should be like this:

```
"public_ipv4": ["10.0.0.1"]
```

So knife ssh command gettin' public_ipv4 from json as an array with [""]

How to remove that square brackets & quotes to knife ssh connect successfully?

Thx in advance.

Comment: any glue?.. i think, brackets & quotes are the reason of error

Comment: `DEBUG: establishing connection to ["node-ip-address"]:22`

Comment: Should be `DEBUG: establishing connection to node-ip-address:22`

Comment: Couse of cloud.public_ipv4 attribute is an array, and cloud_v2.public_ipv4 is not, use it to get an external ip address without [""]. Solved.  

`knife ssh name:* "some command" -a cloud_v2.public_ipv4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause of cloud.public_ipv4 attribute is an array, and cloud_v2.public_ipv4 is not, use it to get an external ip address without [""]. Solved.

```
knife ssh name:* "some command" -a cloud_v2.public_ipv4
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you established that the node attribute "cloud.public_ipv4" returns an valid IP address and secondly is it routeable?

Check the value as follows:

```
knife search node "name:node-name" -a cloud.public_ipv4
```

Comment: In GCE you could add several static external IPs to one instance, in that way json output would be like an array:  `"public_ipv4": ["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2", "...."]`   In case of only one external ip it should be like this  `"public_ipv4": ["10.0.0.1"]`  So `knife ssh` command gettin' `public_ipv4` from json as an array with `[""]`